# How to manipulate a CSV file for Matplotlib using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have the following data and want to draw a multiple-line graph representing the following [a snippet of] data, in this format in a CSV file:

**The Data:**

```
1216,C210,3610
1217,C210,1863
1218,C210,2419
1224,C210,861
1299,C210,2517
1216,C211,3593
1217,C211,1849
1218,C211,2410
1224,C211,859
1299,C211,2504
1216,C212,3595
1217,C212,1847
1218,C212,2407
1224,C212,860
1299,C212,2501
```

**The Goal:**

I would like to visually represent this data as:
[image: Data being represented in CSV file]

**Q:** How can I manipulate the CSV data so that I can create such a graph with Matplotlib and Python?

**The Sticky: What I have done so far but got stuck:**

```
def processing_and_graphing(m_list, c_list):
    with open(csv_dump, 'r') as input_csv_dump_file:
        input_csv = csv.reader(input_csv_dump_file, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=False)

        with open(csv_temp, 'w', newline='') as output_csv_temp_file:
        for machine in m_list:
            write_into_csv_file = csv.writer(output_csv_temp_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

            for row in input_csv:
                if row[0] == machine:
```

**The Difficulty: I am having:**

I'm have tremendous difficulty in trying to reorganise the data that I can give to Matplotlib.

**The Approach: What I am thinking as an approach:**

Is to iterate through the CSV file and dump the data into a temp file, which I can use to generate a graph (could be directly by the CSV or by Panda or alternative method). But I am stuck in trying to rearrange the data.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: It wasn't me, but users generally downvote questions where the poster shows no attempt at all in solving the problem.

Comment: This is for sure not the first question asking for a line plot from csv data. You may want to (re)read the "search and research" part of [ask]. Also, what's lacking here is a clear problem description. As [ask] puts it: "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself."

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use the `pandas` library:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('scratch.csv', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, df in df.groupby('A'):
    df.plot(x='B', y='C', ax=ax, label=label)
```

You can then format the plot using standard matplotlib commands on `fig` and `ax`.

Comment: `that would make the exact plot you want (and then some) in 2-3 lines of code` - If it's that simple, you should post the code, it'd be helpful for **everyone**!

Comment: And you implied (which I agreed with and upvoted), that posters should put some effort in solving the problem. But sure, if you'd like I can edit the code in.

Comment: Yes, I did, because it's what the website asks to users. Regarding your answer, I didn't downvoted it, I just wanted you to know that leaving an answer like that may lead to downvotes since I think you are a new user. But I'd rather wait who downvoted to explain themselves, rather than make assumptions. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Ah, gotcha - thanks for the explanation. Hopefully my edits did make for a more helpful answer.

Comment: It made it better, really! Let's hope the downvoter come back to at least rejudge/explain the action or hopefully leave an upvote like I did.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible approach to the problem. It reads the csv file and then converts it into a pandas dataframe. After that it loops through the ids and creates the plot. I left out eventual changes to make the plot look nicer (like correctly labeling the x axis). Hope it can help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)
df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
ids = df.f0.drop_duplicates()
for id in ids:
    id_data = df[df['f0'] == id]
    plt.plot([0,1,2], id_data['f2'].as_matrix())
plt.show()
```